# ag-grid keep sort icons visible

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ag-grid

I'd like to keep the sort icons visible in table header columns all the time. But the default behavior of ag-grid is hiding the icons (`.ag-header-cell-sorted-asc, .ag-header-cell-sorted-desc`) as soon as I click on any header label.

Is there any option to  change this behavior?

This is how I define the header columns:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-list',
  templateUrl: './test-list.component.html'
})
export class TestListComponent {
    public columnDefs = [
        { headerName: 'Test', field: 'test', minWidth: 150, sort: 'asc' },
        { headerName: 'Test1', field: 'test1', minWidth: 150, sort: 'desc'},
        { headerName: 'Test2', field: 'test2', minWidth: 250 }
      ];
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code in plunker to show what you exactly mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you talking about the unSortIcon?

```
{
        headerName: "Year",
        field: "year",
        width: 90,
        unSortIcon: true
},
```

Have a look at the below plunker example from ag-grid

https://plnkr.co/edit/FylOQ5cAD9id4LbgI3NN?p=preview

See the difference in column 'Year' and all other sort enabled columns? For Year column there is unSortIcon: true is applied.

Comment: thanks, I've actually made it work using a custom component but I knew there would be an easier way.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I was looking for this as well.

Comment: Thank you for this. Tried to use a custom icon for `sortNone` when this boolean `unSortIcon` is set to `true` and it is not appearing.